# How to move a square on x-axis in webgl?

Tags: javascript, animation, webgl

I would like to create an animation where a square should move on x-axis, but i am not sure how to do it.

I am following this tutorial: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/WebGL_API/Tutorial/Adding_2D_content_to_a_WebGL_context

```
  // Tell WebGL how to pull out the positions from the position
  // buffer into the vertexPosition attribute.
  {
    const numComponents = 2;  // pull out 2 values per iteration
    const type = gl.FLOAT;    // the data in the buffer is 32bit floats
    const normalize = false;  // don't normalize
    const stride = 0;         // how many bytes to get from one set of values to the next
                              // 0 = use type and numComponents above
    const offset = 0;         // how many bytes inside the buffer to start from
    gl.bindBuffer(gl.ARRAY_BUFFER, buffers.position);
    gl.vertexAttribPointer(
        programInfo.attribLocations.vertexPosition,
        numComponents,
        type,
        normalize,
        stride,
        offset);
    gl.enableVertexAttribArray(
        programInfo.attribLocations.vertexPosition);
  }

  // Tell WebGL to use our program when drawing

  gl.useProgram(programInfo.program);

  // Set the shader uniforms

  gl.uniformMatrix4fv(
      programInfo.uniformLocations.projectionMatrix,
      false,
      projectionMatrix);
  gl.uniformMatrix4fv(
      programInfo.uniformLocations.modelViewMatrix,
      false,
      modelViewMatrix);

  {
    const offset = 0;
    const vertexCount = 4;
    gl.drawArrays(gl.TRIANGLE_STRIP, offset, vertexCount);
  }
```

i tried to draw scene with for loop, but it happens so fast and didn't looked like an animation and setTimeout also didn't worked.

Comment: The easiest way that doesnt involve recomputing the vertex locations is to modify the modelview matrix to add a translation on the X axis.

Comment: @AKX Sorry, i am new new to webgl and don't know exactly how to do it (move a square from point A to point B smoothly). Can you please provide a piece of code that i could study. That'll be a great help.

Comment: If you are following that tutorial, there's a line with `// amount to translate`. Try changing the values in the translation array.

Comment: As for animating, that's just redrawing the scene at different times -- look at `requestAnimationFrame()`.

Comment: @AKX Thankyou it did what i wanted.